# Fix issue with Confluent Schema Registry: Register operation failed because schema is too large; error code: 42209

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

I have been receiving such errors as in the title:

```
Caused by io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException:
Register operation failed because schema is too large; error code: 42209
```

Suspect it may due many optional and unions from the MongoDB Debezium connector trying to parse MongoDB data into an AVRO schema.

There were also times when the MongoDB Debezium connector would crash with a

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I've increased the Heap space on the Kafka statefulsets.

Currently, our Kafka stateful sets is up on Kubernetes with the following Heap space allocated:

```
env:
  - name: KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS
    value: "-Xmx6G -Xms3G -XX:+UseG1GC"
```

Resources of the Kafka statefulsets is set at:

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 8Gi
    cpu: "1"
  requests:
    memory: 2Gi
    cpu: "0.5"
```

Resources of the Confluent SchemaRegistry deployment is set at:

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 6Gi
    cpu: "1"
  requests:
    memory: 1Gi
    cpu: "0.2"
```

Is there any way I could configure the Confluent Schema registry to accept a larger schema?

Comment: Confluent Schema Registry stores schemas in a special Kafka topic. By default, the maximum Kafka message size is 1 megabyte. You would need to [configure Kafka for a larger message size](https://www.baeldung.com/java-kafka-send-large-message).